# Checking if there are enough quotation marks in the command line - java

Tags: java, input, command-line, args

I'm trying to merge to lists of numbers together into one by using command line (args[0] and args[1])

Incidentally, I want to check if there are enough quotation marks (since the required format is ("list of numbers one" "list of numbers two")) to know if I continue on with the rest of the program.

I tried putting args[0] and args[1] in two different strings and checking if they have quotation marks, but they don't.

I was wondering how I can check for the number of quotation marks in the command line.

Here is what I have so far :

```
String exampleString = "\"12 1 14 -3 7\"" + "\"45 2 16 -6\"";

        int quoteCounter = 0;

        for(int i=0; i < args[0].length(); i++) {
            if(args[0].charAt(i) == '"') {
                quoteCounter++;
                }
            }
        for(int i=0; i < args[1].length(); i++) {
            if(args[1].charAt(i) == '"') {
                quoteCounter++;
                }
            }

        if (quoteCounter != 4) {
            System.out.println("Run the program again and respect the following format please (as many numbers as you want can be inputted) : \"" + exampleString + "\"");
            System.exit(1);
        } else {
            }
```

Comment: Here you go, I added a question.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I don't use a debugger, I only use a compiler.

Comment: @AdrienAacha You definitely don't need a debugger to debug code. You can use printing and other debugging techniques.

Comment: I do use printing, but there are no particular printing problems I can show. It's more of something I'd need to understand before moving on with the rest of my code.

Comment: Adrien, PLEASE read the article I provided on how to debug.  Stack Overflow is NOT a debugging service.  You cannot expect to dump broken code on here and have us fix it.  We expect you to have at least made an effort to find your problem yourself, and frankly, I see no reason to believe you have.

Comment: And I need YOU to understand there is no debugging problem, the only problem here is that I'd like to perform an action, searched it on the internet but didn't find anything. It's also more broadly why I use stackoverflow and not google, if I have to argue why I'm asking a question :)

Comment: @JoeC It's not about broken code, the quotation marks don't appear at all in his command line arguments.

Comment: ...which, with some debugging, would have become clearer and led to a question such as "why aren't my quotes appearing in my command line arguments?", which IMO is a much better question.

Comment: that's not my question. I want to check the command line to see if there ARE quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check for any quotation marks.

If you invoke `C:/> run.exe "1 2 3 4 5" "6 7 8 9 10"` (ignore the fact that Java generally doesn't generate `.exe` files as it doesn't matter), the argument list will contain `1 2 3 4 5` and `6 7 8 9 10` (and `run.exe`, of course), because quotation marked strings ignore spaces.

The args themselves don't get the quotation marks.

Each item in it is one quotation marked string, so you can simply compare the length of the `args` array to 2.

Comment: The problem is that the length of args 0 and args 1 can change. There is no definite length to respect. That's what makes it hard for me

Comment: @AdrienAacha It doesn't matter. You don't look into the arguments themselves, you just check how many are they.

Comment: It does matter. For example, let's say my input is : "3 6 9 8 4 5 4" 5 6 1 3 4 55. args[0] will receive : "3 6 9 8 4 5 4" and args[1] : 5. Also, I'd like that the user respects the format.

Comment: @AdrienAacha In the case you stated, what should be the result? (error or not?)

Comment: In the case I stated, the program should return that, because there aren't enough quotation marks in the command line, there is an error, yes.

Comment: Great. The array `args` will be `{"3 6 9 8 4 5 4", "5", "6", "1", "3", "4", "55"}`, right? Which is more than 2, and is indeed wrong. However `"3 6 9 8 4 5 4" "5 6 1 3 4 55"` will result in `{"3 6 9 8 4 5 4", "5 6 1 3 4 55"}`. (In the whole comment quotation marks are for Java Strings, not for the actual chars.)

Comment: Yes, but checking for the number of args doesn't work either because I want the input to be specific (i.e. with quotation marks and two lists only).

Comment: Can the lists contain only one value?

Comment: They can yes, they can contain x value.

Comment: Then you can't verify it, I think. The command line strips the quotation marks for you and you have no way to differ between `C:/> run.exe a` and `C:/> run.exe "a"` (As much as I know)

Answer (score -1):

This code should do the trick:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main
{
    /* This method checks whether a given argument is valid
     */
    private static boolean isValidArgument(String arg)
    {
        return arg.startsWith("\"") && arg.endsWith("\"");
    }

    /* This method converts an argument into a Set<Integer>
     */
    private static Set<Integer> toIntegerSet(String arg)
    {
        Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();
        for(String part : arg.substring(1, arg.length()-1).split(" "))
        {
            s.add(Integer.parseInt(part));
        }
        return s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String arg0 = "\"1 2 3 4 5\"";
        String arg1 = "\"5 6 7 8 9\"";
        if(!isValidArgument(arg0))
            System.err.println("Invalid argument at index 0");
        if(!isValidArgument(arg1))
            System.err.println("Invalid argument at index 1");

        // merge into a set (to avoid duplicates)
        Set<Integer> mergedSet = toIntegerSet(arg0);
        mergedSet.addAll(toIntegerSet(arg1));

        // turn into a list (to sort)
        List<Integer> mergedList = new ArrayList<>(mergedSet);
        java.util.Collections.sort(mergedList);

        // turn into array (for displaying)
        Integer[] mergedArray = mergedList.toArray(new Integer[mergedList.size()]);
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(mergedArray));
    }
}
```

Or check the live version on IdeOne

https://ideone.com/Ow2eEQ

Comment: To whoever downvoted this, can you at least comment on why you're downvoting it? Or is it merely because you want your answer to be the top one?